Enhancing the predictive capability of traditional node-similarity indices with the Node2Vec algorithm
I am trying to test enhancing the prediction capabilities of traditional node-similarity algorithms, like the Jaccard Coefficient or Adamic Adar, with graph embeddings, like the Node2Vec. I think it makes sense because the traditional ones focus more on local topologies of the network, while the Node2Vec is better at understanding the global features of the network. However, I am not a data scientist. What would you think of this?
